# Tensorflow probablity layer with mixed distribution families per-component?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow-probability

I want to train a neural net where output is tensorflow-probability distributions, similar to https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Probabilistic_Layers_VAE. However unlike the link, I need different distribution families for different components of the output.

So far I've tried following.

1. Just have a list of distributions as the output:

```
def loss(x, rv_x):    
    return -rv_x[0].log_prob(x[:, :2]) - rv_x[1].log_prob(x[:, 2:])

inputs  = tf.keras.Input(shape=(15, 4), name='input')

l01 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, input_shape=(15, 4))(inputs)
l02 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, input_shape=(15, 4))(inputs)
l1 = tfp.layers.IndependentNormal((2))(l01)
l2 = tfp.layers.IndependentBernoulli((4))(l02)

md = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[l1, l2], name="dummy")
md.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.7e-4))
```

The model is successfully compiled but at the training I have following error

```
AttributeError: in user code:

    /home/piotr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    <ipython-input-7-bab2b14facbc>:4 loss1  *
        return -rv_x[0].log_prob(x[:, :2]) - rv_x[1].log_prob(x[:, 2:])

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'log_prob'
```

2. I also tried to avoid lists in the loss function by wrapping output in `DistributionLambda` like follows

```
def loss(x, rv_x):
    log_prob_parts = rv_x.log_prop_parts(x)
    return -tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.concat(log_prob_parts, axis=2))

inputs  = tfk.Input(shape=(15, 4), name='input')

l0 = tfk.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(15, 4))(inputs)
l1 = tfpl.DistributionLambda(
    make_distribution_fn = lambda t: 
        tfd.JointDistributionSequential(
                          [tfd.Cauchy(t[:,:,0:1],  tf.abs(t[:,:,1:2])), 
                           tfd.Normal(t[:,:,2:5],  tf.abs(t[:,:,5:8]))])
               ,  name = 'output_distribution')(l0)
    
md = tfk.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=l1, name="dummy")
md.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=tfk.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.7e-4))
```

Here again, the model is  compiled but the error at training is now

```
AttributeError: in user code:

    /home/piotr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/piotr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
...
/home/piotr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:749 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /home/piotr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:202 __call__
        y_t, y_p, sw = match_dtype_and_rank(y_t, y_p, sw)
    /home/piotr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:617 match_dtype_and_rank
        if ((y_t.dtype.is_floating and y_p.dtype.is_floating) or

    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_floating'
```

May be I am looking in wrong direction, but I have ideas depleted.
Any help is appreciated.